# Composer stuck in Terminal

Tags: magento-2.1, command-line

When I want to intergrade a new plugin through composer I get an error from a attempt of intergrating a tool through the command line. How do I remove this and try to add the following tool:

`composer require dealer4dealer/xcore-magento2`

Error is:

`[RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://***:***@github.com/rusdragos/m2-weltpixel-google-tag-manager.git' '/root/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-rusdragos-m2-weltpixel
  -google-tag-manager.git/'
  Cloning into bare repository '/root/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-rusdragos-m2-weltpixel-google-tag-manager.git'...
  remote: Repository not found.
  fatal: repository 'https://***:***@github.com/rusdragos/m2-weltpixel-google-tag-manager.git/' not found`

Answer (score 0):

The repository composer is trying to download does not exist anymore https://github.com/rusdragos/m2-weltpixel-google-tag-manager (dead link).
If you need the module you can download it from [here](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html)  and install it manually in `app/code` but if this module is a dependency for another module I guess you cannot use that module.

End you can get the xcore (whatever that is) magento extension from here: https://github.com/dealer4dealer/magento2-restapi.
It does not have any dependencies it's composer.json file. So I guess the problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: I understand that it does not work anymore. The problem is that it's stuck in the composer. I am searching for dealer4dealer/xcore-magento2 now, not for m2-weltpixel-google-tag-manager.

How do I get it out

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: I think that this doesn't solve the fact that with any composer action it still gives me the mistake.

Comment: Ok . This is totally different. Check the `composer.json` file for any occurrences of `weltpixel` and remove them.

Comment: I removed them, but when I work on the composer now I get a bigger error. I will adjust my question with it.